# Using Model Builder iterators to create unique shapefiles from one big shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm trying to use Model Builder in ArcMap to split one shapefile with multiple entries into unique ones and then create individual buffers for each of them. See image for the table.

I think it should be possible to have the one shapefile as input file and then some iterator that checks each row and then creates a new shapefile out of that and then finally adds all of them into the Buffer tool and in the end creates several buffer polygons for each new shapefile.

However, all my attempts thus far generates just one buffer polygon.

[image: Attribute table of the shapefile]

[image: Model]

Edit: I succeeded in splitting the shapefile into several unique ones, however I still only get one buffer for them all. Added model image.

[image: Model image]

Comment: Show your model. Have you tried "Split by attribute" tool?

Comment: I edited the post with the model. I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1 so that tool doesn't exist but I found a similar one which I downloaded and that works fine, however still one buffer for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "wrong" iterator. It is for iterating over different feature classes, not individual features in a feature class. Try [Iterate Feature Selection](https://www.google.com/search?q=Iterate%20Feature%20Selection&ie=&oe=):

> Iterates over features in a feature class

In later versions of ArcGIS you could have used "Split by attributes" tool.

Comment: I see. I have access to a version of ArcGIS which have Split by attributes but I can't link the output from that to "Iterate Feature Selection", see added image in the original post.